# Alarm Clock with song or playlist & no repeat

Tags: ios, alarm-clock

Would feel like a simple request but so far this one option has eluded me.

So, I need an iOS alarm clock that will play a song or playlist as its alarm sound.

The only feature I'm looking for that has so far eluded me is - the option to only play the song/playlist **once** without repeating.
The idea is then it will do the same at the next alarm time, without user intervention [though intervention is optional, the single play is paramount.]

I need this not as an alarm clock to wake me in the morning, but for a very specific timer event that must have a single play-through of whatever is chosen.

Single song or playlist - either is acceptable - I can easily turn my playlist into what iTunes would consider to be a single 'tune'.

I would list what I've already tried - but there are so many with 'alarm clock' in the title that I really have lost track, so I'm hoping someone knows one with that one feature.

BTW, 'My Music Alarm Clock' says it does this but fails to actually stop playback.